# Javascript: Split string with withespace unless it is enclosed in round brackets, single quotation mark or square bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

My approach:
https://regex101.com/r/vyKG1j/1

```
[\s]+(?!([^[]*])|([^\(]*\)))
```

Unfortunately this has problems with encapsulated brackets ex: (a b (c d)) and I was not able to implement the apostrophe search.

Example: `"a b (a (a b)) [a b c d] 'test string' (a b)"`
Desired results:`["a", "b", "(a (a b))", "[a b c d]", "'test string'", "(a b)"]`

It would be best if it could also handle something like this.

Example: `"a b abcd(a b)"`
Desired results:`["a", "b", "abcd(a b)"]`

Is regex the best approach here?

Comment: Regex is not suitable for nested structures.

Answer (score 1):

The question to ask yourself to know if something can be solved by regular expressions is - `Can I draw a finite automata (state machine) for this problem`. Remember the automata doesn't have any storage capability.

Now let's look at the substring that has nested structure here from your example:
`(a (a b))`

How can you write a `generic` finite automata for this scenario? By `generic` I mean, how will the automata `remember` how many times a opening bracket has occurred to have equal number of matching closing brackets following certain pattern?

And that's why this string pattern can't be parsed using `just` regular expression alone.

And for this problem in particular, since it is so simple, I would just iterate over the string, keeping a stack to track the brackets and quote characters to parse it myself.